# How to secure resources from being extracted?

Tags: java, resources, copy-protection, launch4j

I have a jar file with a resources folder. I have converted it to EXE using Launch4J.

How you can I secure my resources from being extracted using winzip/winrar ?

P.S. I know there is no 100% hacker proof way but I want to make it secure such that user can't access resources with just two clicks.

Comment: There is no 100% hacker proof way to secure your resources - anything that you put in the hands of users can in principle be reverse engineered.

Comment: Yeah, I know but I want to add some basic security such that user can't just unzip it and get access to resources in two clicks!

Answer (score 0):

With java, as far as I know, your options are fairly limited.  I might suggest obfuscating your code, somehow.  For a bit more info, try this answer, [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280702/protecting-java-jar-files-for-distribution)

It may not be extraction-proof, but it's about as good (to some degree), as anyone can open just about any file in a text editor, but it's all gobldygook, which is essentially the same thing you get from obfuscation, only to a lesser degree.  Nonetheless, it's arguably your best bet with java code.