# Set Java Application for only one Computer System

Tags: java, security, netbeans, privacy

I am working on a project and I want my application to be run on only one system!
All I want is that when I deliever my project to one particular and he can not be able to copy my project and can run on any other computer system.
I am working on Java 8 IDE(NetBeans).

Thanks

Comment: You an refer this link :


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280702/protecting-java-jar-files-for-distribution


I hope it helps !!!

Comment: Or check for mac address of the system to confirm it's the same system you want :-)

Comment: the MAC address can easily be changed by any logged-on user or running application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you need an offline solution you can use any of these features

[Get hardware details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29)

but always the best answer is to keep part of the application inside your own server , when installing the application you can complete it only for this particular this machine .

### Two Ways

Way No.1

- build your own Web service which completes your applications functionalities , and when the application uses this web service ,you need to make sure this is the same machine (by the IP , mac address , )

---

Way No.2

- when installing collect the hardware information & send it to your server to save it there.
- then when using any offline feature you need to request from the server the permission to do so , by regenerating the machine information

put in your mind that someone can reverse engineering your code , so I prefer always the first way

Answer (score 1):

You can ask client for his `MAC` address and include it in your code then using java code obtain the `MAC` address of the computer the executes it and then compare the same to the client's `MAC` initially stored in your program. In case of mismatch code for the program termination of your program.
You can find the code for retrieving the MAC id from the following example 
[Get MAC Address of System in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448995/get-mac-address-of-system-in-java)

Comment: this provides no identification-security whatsoever.

Comment: so, any other choice than MAC add?

Comment: literally everything. The whole operating system & hardware, but you will have a hard time with java

Answer (score 0):

short answer : "you cant".

long answer : its nigh-impossible to restrict your application to one single machine - it takes years of development to be able to implement **minor** machine-restrictions; just look at all the modern games -- most of them have some kind of DRM in them, all of which get cracked swiftly by **teenagers**.

Now : you could read a few values which **might** be unique to your system, you can also write & search a few specific registry-values - but all that wont help you if your user really wants to copy your app, even cloning an OS and writing it onto the HDD of a second computer is no problem nowadays.

tl;dr : if you actually need to implement working DRM ... well ... you wont get far with java, that requires very complex, native code. With java, the best you can do is obfuscating your code - only paid crackers are able to crack a well-obfuscated java-application and those will also have no hard time cracking your native application.

Comment: you really should get yourself acquainted with something called "google"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)